# I can't connect to MySql from another machine

Tags: windows, mysql

I have installed Apache, PHP, MySql on a Windows 2008 Server. The problem is that I am trying to connect to MySql from my home machine. I have enabled TCP/IP networking in the MySql Configuration Wizard and opened the port (3306) in the firewall (for my home ip). But when trying to connect with HeidiSql , I am getting error 1130 the host is not allowed to connect.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Hang on, so your Server 2008 machine is in work and you are trying to connect to it from home? And the webserver/database server is *directly* connected to the internet?

Comment: If you think his set up is flawed, then say so.. asking condescending rhetorical questions helps no one.

Comment: @Safado - I don't know if it is - I was asking for clarification as the OP does not make it obvious.

Comment: I don't really get what's going on here but yeah the webserver is connected "directly" to the internet, otherwise it would be a rather pointless webserver, or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the grants for your user.

In MySQL, grants are defined by the couple *login, host*.
Maybe your user is only allowed to connect from localhost.

A `show grants for user@'%';` will show you if you are allowed to connect, or not.

Comment: This is one thing I didn't understand when I first started to learn mysql. THe user's are basically set up as `user@location`. If you do a `select user,host from mysql.user;` you can see all the users that are allowed to connect and where they can connect from. Then you use the `show grants` command that Jeremy mentioned to see what permissions they have to what databases/tables.

Comment: the query show grants for user@'%'; gives me this:
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'hmadmin' on host '%
'

Comment: the query select user,host from mysql.user gives me my three users (root and two more) and localhost on all three

Comment: Jeremy C. & @Safado: You guys have solved my problem. I created a user like 'username'@'myhomeip' and gave him some grants and that worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I believe remote connections are enabled by default. See this article for step by step on how to enable:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score -1):

On your server run mysql from command line:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

Then run this command in mysql shell:

```
>use mysql
>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Have a nice time.

Comment: One sure fire way to bring yourself to the attention of the system is to post identical answers to questions - please don't. Also from a security point of view allowing root to access from anywhere isn't great either.